# Hive and Impala and their interaction with HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, filesystems, hdfs, impala

Despite having worked with traditional databases for years, I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how Hive and Impala interact with HDFS (or just how HDFS works itself!) and would like some advice.

Just to set the stage on how I think: On Windows, when I create a file (bob.txt, say), that file is stored "on the filesystem" (NTFS). Now, whether I use Windows Explorer, the Command Prompt, or other software, I will always see bob.txt because it exists "on the filesystem" and all software can access the filesystem.

In my noobie interactions with HDFS using Cloudera on RedHat, I don't believe it works exactly as stated in the previous paragraph.

For example, when using Hue, if I create a table in the "Hive Query Editor", the table doesn't seem to show up under the list of tables when in the "Impala Query Editor". Similar occurs when I use "hive" and "impala-shell" from the command prompt. But, that doesn't make sense to me, since the tables should just be "on the filesystem" -- HDFS, in this case.

A similar action occurs when using sqoop to pull from Oracle.  Why would I need to use the "--import-hive" option when the table I'm pulling from Oracle should just be placed "on the filesystem". Once on the HDFS filesystem, any piece of software sitting on top of it -- such as Hive, Impala, or whatever -- should just be able to access it.

In any case, some of this may be noobie user error(s)/misunderstanding(s), so apologies up front!

And thanks in advance for any comments/advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to be missing an understanding of the *Hive Metastore*. Yes, tables are placed "on the filesystem". In fact, all databases are just "files on disk". Other databases may additionally maintain index files or write ahead logs, but what actually defines *the table*? A schema. And in Hive and Impala (and almost all compatible SQL on Hadoop tools) , they require you to store the schema actually in a relational database called the metastore.

> if I create a table in the "Hive Query Editor", the table doesn't seem to show up under the list of tables when in the "Impala Query Editor".

That's actually a bug in Hue that it doesn't refresh the tables immediately. I thought I saw in a new Hue release, it's fixed, but in any case, Impala has a special `INVALIDATE METADATA` query to rebuild its index of the tables available.

> Why would I need to use the "--import-hive" option when the table I'm pulling from Oracle should just be placed "on the filesystem". Once on the HDFS filesystem, any piece of software sitting on top of it -- such as Hive, Impala, or whatever -- should just be able to access it.

You're right, any tool can access it, however, you still need to run a `CREATE TABLE` somewhere to actually specify how those files are parsed. Pig and Spark can immediately read the data without accessing Hive metastore, but you'll still need to parse out columns yourself, and depending  on the format of the files, every field will be a string

Comment: Thank you so much for your insightful answer! I realize I have a lot to read! :-)